# MVC render partial view foreach inside a popup modal in another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

i have this foreach in my partial view and i want to render partial view inside a popup modal in another view every thing is rendered except the foreach so it doesn't bring the products from the database 
here's the partial view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<InternetApp.Models.Cart>
<h2>this is my Partial view</h2>
<h1>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.product.name)</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{


    <h3>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product.name)
    </h3>
    <h3>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product.price)
    </h3>

}
```

and this is how i render my partial view inside the modal in the other view:

```
        <div class="modal-body ">
            @Html.Partial("_ShowCart",new List<InternetApp.Models.Cart>())
        </div>
```

why the foreach is not rendered and how should i solve it ?

Comment: Is `new List<InternetApp.Models.Cart>()` just for the example sake? Otherwise it seems you're passing in an empty collection, so @foreach() simply has zero items in it.

Comment: @BenSampica oh,so how can i pass the model to html.partial without making an instance ?

Comment: @ZiadMohamed you should pass the list populated from the database instead of new List<InternetApp.Models.Cart>()

Answer (score 0):

If the parent view has the same model, pass your `Model` into the `@Html.Partial` tag. Otherwise, if the parent view has the collection inside of it pass it like `Model.CartItems`, where `CartItems` is the name you gave the collection.

Example:

You have a page with a shopping cart (the view). In order to show users their shopping cart on the page, you query a database (or possibly local storage) inside your controller and use the view's model to transfer those shopping cart items to your view. However, your view also shows the users address information and other relevant e-cart things, so you want to put the shopping cart logic in it's own page (a partial view) - this is where you're at today.

```
// CartViewModel.cs

public class CartViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<InternetApp.Models.Cart> CartItems { get; set; } // Your collection of cart items.
    // Other things pertaining to the user's cart.
}
```

```
// CartController.cs
public ActionResult ViewCart(int userId) 
{
   var viewModel = new ViewCartViewModel {
       CartItems = _database.CartItems.GetAllForUser(userId)
   }

   return View(viewModel); // Passing the model to the view.
}
```

```
<div class="modal-body ">
    @Html.Partial("_ShowCart", Model.CartItems) // Because you filled CartItems in the controller, it has items in it.
</div>
```

Comment: i'm new to mvc and i don't understand what collections really are ,so please can you explain with example

Comment: Edited with example